# Apple swift-format update SwiftSyntax for Swift 5.3 toolchain

Tags: swift, formatting, toolchain, xcode12

A build from the master branch of [swift-format](https://github.com/apple/swift-format) fails when executed against the Swift 5.3 toolchain that came with Xcode 12 Beta 2.

Based on the docs and the error message on execution the issue is almost definitely related to the SwiftSyntax versions not matching between swift-format and the Swift 5.3 toolchain. I've tried updating the swift-format `Package.swift` file to build `swift-format` against the SwiftSyntax `release/5.3` branch but still get this error:

> The loaded '_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser' library is from a toolchain that is not compatible with this version of SwiftSyntax

**The question is** what needs to be changed in `swift-format` `Package.swift` to make execution against the Swift 5.3 toolchain work?

The answer may be as "simple" as knowing which SwiftSyntax commit is packaged with the Swift 5.3 toolchain that came with Xcode 12 Beta 2. The answer may also be that I'm being way too bleeding edge for my own good.

[Tony Allevato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307266/tony-allevato) - I think you are the boss on this.

Comment: What's your actual question? Are you asking why the latest fails, or what version is included with XC 12b2, or something else?

Comment: The question is what needs to be changed in `swift-format` `Package.swift` to make execution against the Swift 5.3 toolchain work. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build Xcode 12 compatible version like this:

1. [This revision](https://github.com/apple/swift-format/tree/35fdb4fff0aeb9a506fccdfad98fab16d907c173) of swift-format compatible with Swift 5.3(download it to your computer)
2. In `Package.swift` SwiftSyntax has to be pinned to Swift 5.3 tag

```
    .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax", .revision("swift-5.3-RELEASE")),
```

3. swift build -c release

The binary will be in `.build/release` folder. Though there are some deprecation warnings, it works just fine.